# In eclipse how to create a new cpp file

Tags: android, c++, eclipse

I would like to know how to create a new cpp file in my project using Eclipse.

I created a new cocos2d-x project and imported android project in Eclipse using "File->New->Project->Android->Android Project From Existing Code"

Now when I right click on the classes folder under my project, 
selecting New->Class I could see only option to create a java file.
A dialog shows create a new java class.

Could someone tell me how to create a new cpp file in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Installing c development tools (CDT). Select Window->OpenPerspective->Other->c/c++

Answer (score 0):

Install c development tools (cdt) into your eclipse and you are good to go. The plugins can be downloaded from the eclipse update site

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I forgot to mention that I already installed  c development tools (CDT) and I couldn't see any option to create cpp file. Should I make some other changes?

Comment: Hey, I got the solution, it worked by changing this Window->OpenPerspective->Other->c/c++